# Concurrency in multithreaded WPF/Silverlight/WP apps

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, concurrency, windows-phone-8

Consider the following code:

```
int lastItemIndex = m_listbox.ItemsSource.Count - 1;
var groupItem = m_listbox.ItemsSource[lastItemIndex] as GroupedObservableCollection<ScheduleItem, DateTime>;
```

In a multithreaded environment like WPF/Silverlight/WP, is there any way to ensure that the lastItemIndex really is the last item index on the second row?

Answer (score 1):

WPF, as well as most other UI frameworks is single-threaded by default. Multithreading can occur only when you explicitly do it.

Generally, you should not modify collections accessible by UI controls from other threads - you can use Invoke to marshal your modification request to the main thread and do it there. That way collection will always be accessed and modified only from main thread and you would not have concurrency issues.

Comment: Say that I have a command running in another thread, asking dispatcher to invoke an add to the listbox. Can I be absolutely sure that task don't go in between those two rows?

Comment: Your request will be put in message queue that is processed sequentially by a single thread. So if you use a main thread dispatcher, there would be at max a single request executing at any moment of time, and lastItemIndex would not change between lines.

Comment: What is defined as a request?

Comment: But for the normal UI code running in the main thread, is an event considered a request and dealt with without interruptions (in the same thread) as long as I don't do a thread.Sleep?

Comment: It is executed without interruptions event if you do a Thread.Sleep. It may be "interrupted"  if you use async/await pattern